# Rstudio, configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal

Tags: c++, r

I am a newbie and tried various methods already. I ran into problems from this one problem. please help. I think there are two problems here. 1) my c++ is not uptodate. 2) my GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.

I am using mac 2017.

```
> install.packages("sf")
Installing package into ‘/Users/haoluo/Library/R/3.4/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary source needs_compilation
sf  0.6-1  0.6-3              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘sf’

...

In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/HEAD-41888/include/gdal.h:42:
/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/HEAD-41888/include/cpl_port.h:187:6: error: Must have C++11 or newer.
#    error Must have C++11 or newer.
     ^
1 error generated.
In file included from gdal_test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/HEAD-41888/include/gdal.h:42:
/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/HEAD-41888/include/cpl_port.h:187:6: error: Must have C++11 or newer.
#    error Must have C++11 or newer.
     ^
1 error generated.
configure: Install failure: compilation and/or linkage problems.
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Users/haoluo/Library/R/3.4/library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Either you upgrade you c++ compiler or you just answer `n` to `Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?` and install the compiled older version.

Comment: I fail to see how this is rstudio issue?

Comment: See https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ how to setup compilers on MacOS for R 3.4.x.

Comment: @nicola Thank you so much! I failed to read that in the first place. It caused me hours of additional research and readings.

Answer (score 2):

I failed to read the prompt in the first place. Now the problem has been solved by simply answering **`n`** to the question **`Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?`**

**I want to thank [@nicola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987294/nicola) again for the help!**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpODu.png)